# Delphi JsonTextReader fails to read values

Tags: json, delphi

I have a very weird situation.

This is the JSON I am trying to parse:

```json
[
  {
    "username":"xxx",
    "email":"xxx@gmail.com",
    "custom_title":"xxx title",
    "timezone":"Africa\/Cairo",
    "message_count":"218",
    "alerts_unread":"0",
    "like_count":"385",
    "friend_count":"0"
  }
]
```

This is my parsing code:

```pascal
type
  TUserData = record
    email, timezone: string;
    msg, alerts, likes: integer;
 end;

procedure TDMRest.parseData(var b: TUserData);
var
  jtr: TJsonTextReader;
  sr: TStringReader;
begin
  //RESTResponseLogin.Content has the above json text
  sr := TStringReader.Create(RESTResponseLogin.Content);
  try
    jtr := TJsonTextReader.Create(sr);
    try
      while jtr.Read do
      begin
        if jtr.TokenType = TJsonToken.StartObject then
          process(b, jtr);
      end;
    finally
      jtr.Free;
    end;
  finally
    sr.Free;
   end;
end;

//here there is a problem
procedure TDMRest.process(var c: TUserData; jtr: TJsonTextReader);
begin
  while jtr.Read do
  begin
    if (jtr.TokenType = TJsonToken.PropertyName) then
    begin
      if jtr.Value.ToString = 'email' then
      begin
        jtr.Read;
        c.email := jtr.Value.AsString;
      end;

      if jtr.Value.ToString = 'timezone' then
      begin
        jtr.Read;
        c.timezone := jtr.Value.AsString;
      end;

      if jtr.Value.ToString = 'message_count' then
      begin
        jtr.Read;
        c.msg := jtr.Value.AsInteger;
      end;

      if jtr.TokenType = TJsonToken.EndObject then
      begin
        c.alerts := 0;
        c.likes := 0;
        exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**MY PROBLEM**: In the `process()` code, the first 2 `if` blocks (`email` and `timezone`) can read values into my record.  But when I add other `if` blocks (like `if jtr.Value.ToString = 'message_count' then`), I cannot see the values of my record anymore.

Am I parsing the data properly?

Basically, I need to grab the info from a JSON string and put the data inside a `TUserData` record.

I have found the above pattern in a book titled "Expert Delphi", and I am pretty sure that the `parseData()` function is correct. Probably I am missing something in the process.

The `TDMRrst` is a DataModule; I am giving the function a record, and I'd like the data to be properly parsed.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You're reading message_count `AsInteger` whereas, according to your sample, message_count is a string - which raises an exception.  Surely you were seeing that exception being raised?

Comment: @Jason so should it be c.msg := StrToInt(jtr.Value.AsString);?

Comment: I thought that AsInteger converted my string value into an integer!

Comment: Yes, that would work - assuming you have no control over the sending content

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi: `jtr.Value` is a [`TValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValue), whose [`AsInteger()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TValue.AsInteger) method DOES NOT convert a `string` value to an `integer` value.  `TValue` is designed to mimic the implicit conversions of the Pascal language, and you can't assign a `string` directly to an `integer`. You are probably thinking of `Variant`, which CAN do that kind of conversion.

Answer (score 3):

In the JSON you have shown, *all* of the values are strings, there are no integers.  So, when you call `jtr.Value.AsInteger` for the `message_count` value, it raises a conversion exception that you are not catching.  `TValue.AsInteger` DOES NOT perform an implicit conversion from string to integer for you.

You will have to use `jtr.Value.AsString` instead and convert the string to an integer using `StrToInt()`:

```
if jtr.Value.ToString = 'message_count' then
begin
  jtr.Read;
  //c.msg := jtr.Value.AsInteger;
  c.msg := StrToInt(jtr.Value.AsString);
end;
```

Do the same for the other "integer" values in the JSON (`alerts_unread`, `like_count`, and `friend_count`).

Comment: As far as I remember, Delphi has some kind of JSON to Delphi (and vice versa) object value assignments. You just define object and the rest is done by RTTI and a single method call. Marshaller and unmarshaller.

Comment: It seems to be `TJSONUnMarshal.CreateObject` from `REST.JsonReflect` unit (OP uses REST). You just create `TJSONUnMarshal` instance and pass to the `CreateObject` method desired class type and a JSON object. And if you're lucky enough, you'll get an object instance with no manual parsing. Of course the output structure must be object, not record as records have no RTTI information.

Comment: @Victoria: That appraoch is documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki: [Serializing User Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Serializing_User_Objects). But, does that implicitly convert string values to integer variables? If not, then you will have to define a custom convertor for that operation, or else define the marshaled class to use `String` for its integer values.

Comment: I was hoping in an attribute by which you say how to convert an input JSON string value to an integer field. Cannot find any :(

Comment: @Victoria: maybe something wiith the [`JSONReflect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DBXJSONReflect.JSONReflect) attribute?  I don't use JSON marshaling.

Comment: I'm not using it either. But yes, that's what I was thinking about (specifically [JsonReflectAttribute](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/REST.JsonReflect.JsonReflectAttribute)). I cannot find any list of supported attributes. I was thinking either about a one, by which you use a default (string to integer) converter, or at least a one that allows the field to be processed by a custom converter.

Comment: Sorry, better forget this feature. It seems to be unfinished. REST.JsonReflect unit says _"Currently it is not recommended to use any of this unit directly, as its interface may change over time. Use REST.TJson instead (or Data.DBXJSONReflect). The interfaces in REST.Json can be considered stable."_ Well, interface from REST.Json might be called stable, but fails in its implementation with basic objects (Tokyo). I don't want to spend more time on this, so I won't suggest this feature anymore. Built-in converters can be chosen by field attributes, but if the rest fails to do its work..